# How to find the nth number?

Tags: c, loops

For an assignment, I have to write code which accepts as input an integer n and outputs the nth 'superunusual' number.

The first few su-numbers are: 22, 23, 26, 33, ... So when the input is 1, the output should be 22. 2 gives 23 and 3 gives 26.

I already have a code that checks if the input number is a su-number, but I can't find a way to calculate the nth number.

So when I now input 22, it says that 22 is a superunusual number.

The code:

```c
/* calculates largest prime factor                  */
int lprime(int n) {  
    int max = -1;  

    while (n % 2 == 0) {  
        max = 2;  
        n /= 2;  
    }

    for (int i = 3; i*i <= n; i += 2) {  
        while (n % i == 0) {  
            max = i;  
            n = n / i;  
        } 
    } 

    if (n > 2) { 
        max = n;  
    }
    return max;  
}  

/* check unusual number */ 
int unus(int n) {  
    /* find largest prime of number */  
    int factor = lprime(n);  

    /* Check if largest prime > sqrt(n) */ 
    if ((factor*factor) > n) {  
        return 1; /* true */  
    }  
    else {  
        return 0; /* false */  
    }  
} 

/* delete digit from number                 */
int del(int num, int n) {
    int d = log10(num)+1; /* checks amount of digits */
    int revnew = 0;
    int new = 0;

    for (int i = 0; num != 0; i++) {
            int dig = num % 10;

            num = num / 10;

            if(i == (d - n)) {
                continue;
            } else {
                revnew = (revnew * 10) + dig;
            }
    }

    for (int i = 0; revnew != 0; i++) {
        new = (new*10) + (revnew % 10);
        revnew = revnew / 10;
    }
    return new;
} 

/* driver code */  
int main(int argc, char* v[]) {
    int m=22, n; 
    int x = 0;
    int i = 1;
    int counter = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int d = log10(m)+1;

    while (counter < n) { 
        if (unus(m++)) { 
            counter++;
        } 
    }

        for(unus(m); i < d; i++) {
            int nmin = del(m, i);
            if (unus(nmin)) {  
                continue;
            } else { 
                printf("%d is not supurunusual\n", (m-1)); 
                x++;  
            }
        }

    if(x==0) {
        printf("%d is superunusual!\n", (m-1));
    }
    return 0;  
}
```

I hope you can understand my code. Otherwise I will explain it better.

Also, I'm quite new to coding, so please don't be to harsh...

Comment: So .. what is "su-number" ?

Comment: Oh sorry, su-number = superunusual number.

Comment: This is a number that remains an unusual number (see wikipedia), even with the deletion of one of the digits.

Comment: Anyway, you already have a predicate to test the number. So the naive algorithm would be to to iterate over all of the numbers and count the "su" ones until reaching the given count. Easy, no?

Comment: Yes indeed. I also know that it only lacks that part, but I can't figure out how to do this...

Comment: Something like `while (counter < m) { if (is_super_unusual(n++)) counter++; }`. Of course with proper initialization. Maybe off-by-one somewhere.

Comment: Very helpful code, it works for the input 1, 2 and 3, but for 4 it gives the wrong output and for 5 it keeps running... I now for sure that the functions are correct tho... It's the main part where it's going wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function to determine whether a number is unusual, but you do the check whether a number is super-unusual in the body of the `main` routine. If you extract that code into a proper function:

```
int is_superunusual(int m)
{
    int d = log10(m) + 1;

    if (unus(m) == 0) return 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < d; i++) {             // see footnote
        int nmin = del(m, i);

        if (unus(nmin) == 0) return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

then you can use Eugene's code:

```
while (counter < n) { 
    if (is_superunusual(m++)) { 
        counter++;
    } 
}

printf("The su number #%d is %d\n", n, m - 1);
```

Your code tested for unusual numbers, not super-unusual numbers.

Footnote: If you take `del(num, n)` to mean "remove the nth digit from the end", you can do away with the log10 call in `del`. You must check all deletions anyway, so the order doesn't really matter here.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works a lot better. Only thing is that it now gives the unusual numbers and I need the super-unusual numbers (so, when 1 digit gets deleted, it still remains unusual)

Comment: Er, no, it doesn't? [This code](https://ideone.com/GZyXlV) prints the first five, the 50th and the 500th superunusual number as 22, 23, 26, 33, 35, 213 and 1643. I've changed the code a bit, but have left the overall structure intact. Perhaps there are still errors, but clearly these are su, nut just unusual numbers, no?

Comment: Oops! I didn't test the program with a new compiled file! Stupid...

Comment: It only doesn't work for 100, it should give 389 but gives 283. But I'll figure that out! Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I guess you get some false positives, because you don't check the removal of all digits? (In your original code, `i` goes from 1 to `d`. The code I posted gives 387 as 100th su-number. Still wrong, but closer.)

Comment: Oh! You meant the code behind the "This code"-link. Well that helps a lot more :)

Comment: Have you found the error? Your digit removal code has problems with numbers that end in zeros. [Here's](https://ideone.com/ZeoR6A) a fixed version. And, for good measure, [here](https://ideone.com/flgbpE) is another variant that uses a sieve of Erathostenes and another approach to digit removal. Both give the 100th su number as 389. Have fun!